# Scrolling only one centered flex div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a login page with a splash image. The image is on the left side, has some text overlaid, and should never scroll. The login form is on the right side and should be vertically centered and scroll if necessary. I can't figure out how to accomplish this, however.

[Here's a Codepen](https://codepen.io/vaindil/pen/eYzpMWx), and the code is also below. You can see that this code causes the entire page to scroll rather than just the rightmost div.

Things I've tried:

- Setting the body or container to `overflow: hidden`, but this also prevents the right div from scrolling.
- Setting `height: 100vh` or `100%` on the rightmost div, but this makes the form no longer vertically centered.
- Using `justify-content: center` instead of `margin: auto`, but this cuts off the top of the div when it shrinks enough to need to scroll.

Not really sure what else to try. (This
code also causes a horizontal scrollbar, not sure why, my actual code
doesn't have one.)

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.splash {
  background: url('https://placekitten.com/1920/1080') no-repeat;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.form {
  padding-top: 36px;
  width: 480px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: auto;
}

.block {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="splash"></div>
  <div class="form">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sandbox](https://codepen.io/vakyla98/pen/zYBvjgd)

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.splash {
 position:sticky; 
 top:0; background:url('https://placekitten.com/1920/1080') no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width:600px;
}

.form {
  padding-top: 36px;
  width: 180px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto;
}

.block {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="splash"></div>
  <div class="form">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can try to do this with `position:sticky` , this property helps to glue your block to his parent with `position:relative` , also don't forget about one of the absolute positioning property like a left | right | top | bottom

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/position) you can read more about `sticky` and other types of `position` property.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is recommended to include the full code of the solution here in the SO answer when using an external link like codepen or sandbox, thank you. Also, a little bit of explanations is suggested instead of posting a link to an external resource.

Comment: It is a good solution, but sticky position for now has poor support: https://caniuse.com/?search=sticky

Answer (score 0):

I think the following could work for you:
[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/9Leyj1to/)

Where the child with the form needs to have a max height set and the image one a min height:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.flex > div {
  flex: 1;
}

.left {
  background: url('https://placekitten.com/1920/1080') no-repeat center/cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 15px 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block {
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
}
```